Button inside NavigationLink that's inside a list item not working correctly
I have a button that I would like to link to another view upon clicking on it. I was told to put it inside a NavigationLink, use .borderless button style, but it activates outside of its area on the entire list row. I experimented with using navigation view or disabling the navigationlink among other suggestions but it doesn't fix the problem or just messes up my view so I must be doing something wrong.
Here is the list item view
struct NodeListItem: View {
 var body: some View {
   LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
    //has more information up here I don't think is relevant
     HStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: UserMessageList(user: node.user!)) {
            Button("DM") {
              //don't actually need it to do anything besides changing views
             }
           //.borderless does nothing I want it to have a border
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent) 
            }
        }
     }
  }

Here is my list view
struct NodeList: View {
 var body: some View {
   NavigationStack {
     List(nodes, id: \.self) { node in
        NodeListItem(node: node)
            .contextMenu {
                 Button {
                    node.user!.mute = !node.user!.mute
                    } label: {
                        Label(node.user!.mute ? "Show DM Alerts" : "Hide DM Alerts", systemImage: node.user!.mute ? "bell" : "bell.slash")
                    }
                    
                    if bleManager.connectedPeripheral != nil {
                        Button (role: .destructive) {
                            deleteNodeId = node.num
                            isPresentingDeleteNodeAlert = true
                        } label: {
                            Label("Delete Node", systemImage: "trash")
                        }
                    }
              }
        }
       .listStyle(.plain)
   }
}

Any help/suggestions are appreciated!

What you can try to do is put your navigation link and button into Zstack, the way button is in top of navigation link.

Isn't NavigationLink already kind of a button? AFAIK it's configured using a navigation destination and UI for it (e.g. Text for a simple text button).

You should not use a NavigationLink. You should do the navigation programmatically in the button's action closure.
Assuming the type of nodes is [Node], you can add a @State representing the navigation path like this:
@State private var path: [Node] = []
let nodes = [...]

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        List(nodes, id: \.self) { node in
            NodeListItem(node: node) {
                // programmatic navigation
                path.append(node)
            }
            .contextMenu { ... }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Node.self) { node in
            UserMessageList(user: node.user!)
        }
    }
}

Note that the navigation destination of UserMessageList is declared on the List, instead of each individual NodeListItem.
NodeListItem should be changed to take a closure for its button's action:
struct NodeListItem: View {
    let node: Node
    let buttonAction: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // ...
            HStack {
                // ...
                Button("DM") {
                    buttonAction()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
    }
}

Of course, you can also pass a @Binding of the navigation path, and do path.append in NodeListItem:
struct NodeListItem: View {
    let node: Node
    @Binding var path: [Node]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // ...
            HStack {
                // ...
                Button("DM") {
                    path.append(node)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
    }
}

// ...

NodeListItem(node: node, path: $path)

Personally I think the former makes more sense.

For some reason I was not able to append a node in the NodeListItem like that and compiler told me it couldn't type check the expression, probably something wrong on my part. But the @binding method worked! Thanks a lot! just wondering if in the future if the list gets to be 100+ items if there will be performance concerns or if the app will be able to keep up with so many paths but I'm thinking too far ahead. Thanks!

A NavigationLink is itself a button and normally it can be styled using .buttonStyle in the same way as a regular Button. The reason why this doesn't work here, is because the item is an entry in a List.
However, if you style the label of the NavigationLink yourself, then you can avoid the nested button. Something like this:
NavigationLink {
    UserMessageList(user: node.user!)
} label: {
    Text("DM")
        .padding(.horizontal, 12)
        .padding(.vertical, 7)
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                .fill(.link)
        )
}

The list row still has an arrow at the side and navigation happens when the row is tapped anywhere. If this is the problem you're trying to solve then not using a NavigationLink is probably the way to go -> see the answer by Sweeper for details of how to navigate programmatically instead.

Using this method you can navigate form any button to any other screen and also impose conditions note the buttons are inside a List {} so, It can also manage that.
first create some variable to control i.e  
struct ServicePackage: View {
@State private var selectedService: Service? = nil
@State private var isButtonClick = false
@State private var navigator = 0

then create a method for handling the navigation something like these according to your use
 private func destinationView(for service: Service? ,nav : Int) -> some View {
    guard let service = service else {
        return AnyView(Text("Invalid service"))
    }
    // Decide destination based on the service properties
    if(navigator == 1){
        return AnyView(PackageDescription())
    }
    else if navigator == 2 && !service.proPackages.isEmpty {
        return AnyView(PackageDetails())
    } else if navigator == 2 && service.proPackages.isEmpty {
        return AnyView(PackageCost())
    }else {
        return AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
}

then on the button click impose the navigation i.e
Button(action: {
    selectedService = service
    isButtonClick = true
    navigator = 1
}) {
    Text("See Details >")
        .padding(8)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
}
.background(
    NavigationLink(
        destination: destinationView(for: selectedService, nav: navigator),
        isActive: $isButtonClick,
        label: { EmptyView() }
    )
    .hidden()
)
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

